# Как получить ссылку на изображение (парсер simple_html_dom)?

Tags: парсер

С помощью simple_html_dom получила все данные, что мне нужны, но не получается взять ссылку на картинку от сюда

```
<span itemprop="image" content="https://lh3.ggpht.com/pvG5fFwMsvPcAX8-IojHOBdNHdmrCtr6asadB4D5GoWfZMrXGtNXYQUJT-JMVk5zcb4=w124" />
```

либо от сюда:

```
> <div class="doc-banner-icon"><img
> itemprop="image"src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/pvG5fFwMsvPcAX8-IojHOBdNHdmrCtr6asadB4D5GoWfZMrXGtNXYQUJT-JMVk5zcb4=w124"/></div>
```

Comment: Уточните, что значит "не получается"? Может, приведите ваш код, если он не секретный? (Только не весь, лишь нужный фрагмент.)

Comment: брать пыталась разными путями:

> $link=$html->find('img',0);
> $link=$html->find('div [class=doc-banner-icon] img',0);
> $link=$html->find('img [itemprop=image]',0);


но не один из них не дал мне ссылки

Comment: А что делается для поиска картинок и что конкретно не получается? Например, как найти все span с itemprop - понятно?

Comment: все спаны с итемпропом не искала, сразу искала тот, у которого итемпроп=изображение

Comment: >$link=$html->find('img [itemprop=image]',0);

Это что?

Comment: <img itemprop="image"src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/pvG5fFwMsvPcAX8-IojHOBdNHdmrCtr6asadB4D5GoWfZMrXGtNXYQUJT-JMVk5zcb4=w124"/> - пыталась от сюда взять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стойте-стойте. Что возвращает `$link=$html->find('img',0);`? Самую первую картинку. А вам нужно обойти все картинки. Делайте честно:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
{
   if (isset($element->itemprop))
       // ...
}
```

---

И кстати, а что в вашем `$link`?

Comment: в нее я кидаю ссылку на изображение. а как потом достать из элемента значение поля content?
(извиняюсь за новичковые вопросы)

Comment: Эээ... Ссылка -- это `<a href="url">content</a>`? Попробуйте `$link->innertext`.

Comment: все. разобралась

Comment: @Евгения Форманюк: пожалуйста!